# SQL Server Management Studio - Understanding Stored Procedure variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm wondering if someone could help me out.

I'm very very new to SQL Server Management Studio ... I'm having a look over stored procedures at the moment.

I see a line that says the following

```
@title varchar (50)
```

This is pretty easy to figure out .... create a variable called title and give it the data type of `varchar(50)`

Then, on the next line there is the following:

```
@exampleid int = 1
```

This is the bit I don't understand.

Does this mean to set the field `exampleid` to 1?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 and up, you can use

```
DECLARE @exampleid int = 1
```

This defines a **variable** and immediately assigns the value `1` to it.

Or if this in the head of the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SomeProcedure 
    @exampleid int = 1
    .....
```

then it is a stored procedure **parameter** with a default value of `1` that gets used if you don't specify anything else.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense ... It is in the head, but instead of CREATE, it says ALTER ... Thanks for that, makes sense now

Comment: @BigJobbies: that's okay - the `ALTER` is used to modify an existing stored procedure (while `CREATE` creates a new one if it's not already there)

Answer (score 0):

```
@title varchar (50)  -- It represent  @title a parameter of type varchar(50) passing to Stored Procedures.
@exampleid int = 1 -- A value 1 has been assigned to a parameter
```